# How do you validate a FormBuilder control based on another in Angular2?

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I'm using FormBuilder in Angular2 and I created a custom validator service.

**Component**

```
this.exampleForm  = this.formBuilder.group({
    'FirstName': ['', Validators.required],
    'LastName': ['', [Validators.required]],
    'Description': [''],
    'Location': [''],
});

this.exampleForm .addControl("StartDate", this.formBuilder.group({
    'Month': [0, [Validators.required, ValidationService.monthValidator]],
    'Year': [0, [Validators.required, ValidationService.yearValidator]]
}));

this.exampleForm .addControl("EndDate", this.formBuilder.group({
    'Month': [0],
    'Year': [0]
}));
```

**HTML component**

```
<div formGroupName="StartDate">
    <select formControlName="Month">
        <option>...</option>
        </option>
    </select>
    <select formControlName="Year">
        <option>...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I don't want to have an earlier EndDate than StartDate

How do I validate EndDate control based on StarDate control?

**EDIT**

Tried something like this:

```
this.exampleForm  = this.formBuilder.group({
        ...
    }, passwordMatchValidator);

function passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
   return g.get('FirstName').value === g.get('LastName').value
      ? null : {'mismatch': true};
}
```

It doesn't do anythig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group your two control in a FormGroup and test if this FormGroup is valid
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormGroup-class.html

**EDIT**

By default, a formgroup is valid if every FormControl are valid.
  You can define a custome validator for a FormGroup as you do for a FormControl.
In this example, I added a validator (passwordMatchValidator) to the FormGroup containing two FormControl.

stackoverflow-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'stackoverflow-form',
    templateUrl: 'stackoverflow-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'stackoverflow-form.component.css'
    ],
    providers: []
})
export class StackOverflowFormComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public alphaCtrl: FormControl;
    public betaCtrl: FormControl;

    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.alphaCtrl = fb.control('alphaValue', [StackOverflowFormComponent.myControlValidator]);
        this.betaCtrl = fb.control('betaValue', [StackOverflowFormComponent.myControlValidator]);
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
            alpha: this.alphaCtrl,
            beta: this.betaCtrl,
        }, StackOverflowFormComponent.passwordMatchValidator);
    }

    // Custom FormControl Validator 
    static myControlValidator(control: FormControl) {
        return control.value.length > 1 ? null : { myInvalid: true};
    }

    // Custom FormGroup Validator 
    static passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
        return g.get('alpha').value === g.get('beta').value
            ? null : {'mismatch': true};
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

stackoverflow-form.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input formControlName="alpha" name="alpha"/>
    <input formControlName="beta" name="beta"/>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">SEND</button>
</form>
```

stackoverflow-form.component.css

```
input.ng-invalid {
    background-color: red;
}

input.ng-valid {
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

Comment: but they have same value, they can't be in the same group, right ?

Comment: What I meant is that you can pass the FormGroup (containing your two formControl) to the service.

Comment: how do you pass the formgrup, can you give me an example, if is not to much, please?

Comment: addControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl) : void so you can't use this.exampleForm.addControl("exampleControl1", myFormGroup). I'm writing an example.

Comment: But how do you add the other controls from the other group ?

Comment: Can you be more precise please ? What FormControls and FormGroup are you talking about ?

Comment: Ok, to the code in my question, i just added your validator to the whole group. Doesn't seem to validate. I tried validating firstname, lastname

Comment: Ok. In your code you're using FormBuilder.group whereas in my example I use the constructor FormGroup(). Did you check that ? In my example if i use a FormBuilder to create the FormGroup the code should be: `this.myForm = fb.group(
            {
                alpha: ['', StackOverflowFormComponent.myControlValidator],
                beta: ['', StackOverflowFormComponent.myControlValidator],
            },
            { 
                validator: StackOverflowFormComponent.passwordMatchValidator
            }
        );`

Comment: Glad  to help you. Voila, my first bounty on StackOverflow ;)